# opcion de sonido hdmi ubuntu 22.01 no aparece en la pestaña de configuracion de sonido

Tags: linux, ubuntu

siempre he ocupado mi cable hdmi para mi televisor y siempre habia funcionado bien, pero un dia ubuntu me pidio actualizar el S.O y bueno lo hice despues queria activar el sonido hdmi y no aparecia,probe en otro notebook y el cable funciona... que pudo haber sido? sera un error de la actualizacion?? porfavor ayuda

intente probar si era la tv y tampoco todo funciona bien solo que no aparece la opcion de cambiar sonido a hdmi

Comment: estoy en las mismas. Tengo varios pc y lo que hice fue tomar ubuntu18 y actualizar. No hay otra más rápida solución. Por otro lado nadie contesta. Así que te dejo lo que me funcionó ... y varias veces. Saludos.-

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es sobre programación. [su] o [ubuntu.se] serían más adecuados para esta pregunta.